# SQL Server, Getting All Mondays between two dates

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012

Using this suggestion from another [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30778266/2858221):

Works perfectly fine in `SSMS`, but when trying to use it as a query to create a Dataset for a `SSRS` report, I am getting the following error:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column
>   "dt" of recursive query "CTE".

The `DateFrom` and `DateTo` fields are parameters of data type `Date/Time`, so I've got no idea why it's not working.

Comment: The datatype here `DECLARE @DateFrom DateTime` is very important make sure in SSRS also you are doing the same

Comment: Can you add the exact code of your query in dataset?

Comment: The exact code is the one pinched from the question linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this way,

*First, create dataset using below SQL Query*

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATE;
DECLARE @DateTo DATETIME;

DECLARE @DateCollection TABLE(DateValue DATETIME)
WHILE @DateFrom <= @DateTo
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @DateCollection (DateValue)
    VALUES ( @DateFrom )
    SET @DateFrom = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateFrom)
END

SELECT DateValue FROM @DateCollection WHERE  DATEPART(weekday, Datevalue) = 2
```

- Here, 2 Means Monday

*So, once dataset is created you will have to add two parameters manually for your report. Named as @DateFrom and @DateTo*

Now, please add both parameters manually check below image,

[image]

Then, remove those both declare variables from Dataset and ignore whatever alert shows while saving.

Now, Run and check the table data. I have checked my demo and it's working.

**Demo Run Image:**

[image]

*Hope this will help out you! Let me know if you need more help.*

Comment: Just doing to first part of this, without changing from the CTE style, by saving with the Declare function, saving then adding the parameters of the same name and re-saving seemed to fix the issue. Seems very finicky!

Comment: Okay thanks for the update. If it helped you then please mark as it answer! :)