# T SQL First Tuesday between date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, dateadd

Using SQL Server, I need to work out the 1st Tuesday between a 'bucket start' date and a 'bucket end' date.   However, my code is returning the wrong date.

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])) AS  Bucket_Start,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_END])) AS Bucket_End,
    DATEADD(dd, - 6, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, dateadd(dd, 7 - DATEPART(day, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))),   
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_END])))), 0)) AS [1st_Tuesday]
FROM 
    [BUCKETS]
WHERE 
    CAT_CODE = 1013
    AND BUCKET_START < CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
    AND BUCKET_END > CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
```

And these are the current results:

```
Bucket_Start      Bucket_End      1st_Tuesday
2019-03-31        2019-04-27      2019-03-26
```

However, the correct 1st_Tuesday is:

```
Bucket_Start      Bucket_End      1st_Tuesday
2019-03-31        2019-04-27      2019-04-02
```

Why is my query still looking in March?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777605/find-mondays-between-2-dates

Comment: If bucket start is a sunday add two days, monday then add 1 day, and so on.

Comment: @SAS - not a duplicate - I only want to return 1 record, that link is returning 4

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this by using case statement .

```
    SELECT 
CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])) AS Bucket_Start,
CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_END])) AS Bucket_End,
case when     abs((select  DATEparT(weekday  ,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))))) in  (1,2,3)
                  then    DATEadd(weekday,  3 -  abs((select  DATEparT(weekday  ,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))))), CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])))
                  else   DATEadd(weekday,  3 + ( 7 - abs((select  DATEparT(weekday  ,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])))))), CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])))  
                  end AS [1st_Tuesday]
FROM [BUCKETS]
WHERE   BUCKET_START < CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
AND BUCKET_END > CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help!  I have gone with the below:

```
SELECT
DATENAME(dw,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))) as Bucket_Start_Day, 
CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])) AS Bucket_Start,
CASE
WHEN
DATENAME(dw,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))) = 'Sunday' then 
DATEADD(DD,2,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])))
WHEN
DATENAME(dw,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))) = 'Monday' then 
DATEADD(DD,1,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])))
WHEN
DATENAME(dw,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))) = 'Tuesday' then 
CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))
WHEN
DATENAME(dw,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))) = 'Wednesday' then 
DATEADD(DD,6,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])))
WHEN
DATENAME(dw,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))) = 'Thursday' then 
DATEADD(DD,5,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])))
WHEN
DATENAME(dw,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))) = 'Friday' then 
DATEADD(DD,4,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])))
WHEN
DATENAME(dw,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START]))) = 'Saturday' then 
DATEADD(DD,4,CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), [BUCKET_START])))
END AS '1st_Tuesday'
FROM [BUCKETS]
WHERE CAT_CODE = 1013
AND BUCKET_START < CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
AND BUCKET_END > CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
```

This gives me the below:

```
Bucket_Start_Day    Bucket_Start               1st_Tuesday
Sunday          2019-03-31 00:00:00.000    2019-04-02 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you are asking for but I'm sure you can use it to get your required results.

```
DECLARE  @Day INT = 3;
 --Sunday    1
 --Monday    2
 --Tuesday   3
 --Wednesday 4
 --Thurday   5
 --Friday    6
 --Saturday  7 
 DECLARE  @StartDate DATETIME = GETDATE();

 SELECT  DATEADD(DD, @Day - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) + IIF(@Day - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) >= 0, 0, 7), @StartDate)
```

Change >= to > if you want the next not including today